# perl regular expression take out text enclosed in parentheses

Tags: regex, perl

how do I use Perl to get rid of text within parentheses?  For example:
$str = "This is a (extra stuff) string."
to 
$str = "This is a string."

I am current using this but it's not working:
$str =~ s/( ( [^)]+ ) )//;

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the parentheses, like:

```
s/\([^)]*\)//g
```

---

**Update** by popular demand:

To remove the space you can simply remove spaces before the parenthesis. This will work in most cases:

```
s/\s*\([^)]*\)//g
```

To handle nested parenthesis you can use a recursive pattern, like so:

```
s/\s*\((?:[^()]+|(?R))*\)//g
```

You can read about `(?R)` and the like in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns).

The last expression will work for string like `aaa (foo(b,a,2*(3+4)) b) (c (c) c) ddd (x).`, giving `aaa ddd.`.

Comment: 30s faster:) but just since I wrote only the regex and SO told me I can't answer with a so short answer

Comment: to match the example, you also need to remove the leading or trailing space

Comment: -1: This has problems with spacing and with multiply-nested parentheses.

Comment: @David Hammen, OP never asked for that, nor implied anything about nested parentheses. I just fixed what was wrong with his regex attempt.

Comment: Close, but '(Preliminary remark) string' -> ' string'. But thanks for the info on the new (perl 5.10) PARNO regex feature. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

The ( are special and must be escaped

```
s/\([^)]+\)//g
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions so far do that the OP asked.

- The expression `$str =~ s/\([^)]*\)//g;`

  - Converts "This is a (extra stuff) string" to "This is a  string", leaving two spaces between the "a" and "string".
  - Converts "This is a (doubly (nested)) string" to "This is a ) string".
  - Converts "This is a (doubly (no, (triply!) nested) expression) string" to "This is a  nested) expression) string".
- Similar problems exist with `$str =~ s/[ ]?\(.*?\)[ ]?//g;` And why use those square brackets? Aren't regular expressions hairy enough without unneeded stuff?

We're going to need something a bit hairier to so we can eat multiply-nested parenthetical remarks and properly deal with keeping spacing where needed but discarding it otherwise. This does the trick:

```
1 while $str =~ s/(\w?)(\s*)\([^()]*\)(\s*)(\w?)
                 /($1&&$4)?($1.($2?$2:$3).$4):($1?$1:$4)/ex;
```

**Edit**
Test results:

```
'This string is OK as is.' -> 'This string is OK as is.'
'This is a (extra stuff) string.' -> 'This is a string.'
'(Preliminary remark)  string' -> 'string'
'String (with end remark)' -> 'String'
'A string (remark before punctuation)!' -> 'A string!'
'A (doubly (nested)) string' -> 'A string'
'A (doubly (no, (triply!) nested)) string' -> 'A string'
```

**Edit2**
The `exg` qualification results in incorrect handling of "This (delete) (delete) is a string". All that is needed is `ex`.

Comment: If you gonna handle nesting with regex, at least do it right without rerunning the replace for every match.

Comment: Try and do it without. The above handles things like "a (delete) simple (delete) (delete)(delete ((delete(delete))delete)) string" properly. Using the `/g` qualifier does not.

Comment: Relax a little in your comments on other answers.  The question was contradictory: the title question didn't involve removing whitespace but the example did.  In such a case, you can guess which was meant, but you can't *know*.  And no one knows if there is any need to handle nested parentheses; if there isn't your code may indeed produce the wrong answer for `This is a string (containing a ')')`

Comment: BTW, you have a problem with `$str = '0 ()'`

Answer (score 0):

This line should do what you need:

```
$str =~ s/[ ]?\(.*?\)[ ]?//g;
```

Do note that it won't work with nested brackets (like (this)), since the regex would have to be a lot more complicated for that type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I do converting special characters to hex for easy use in my regex's

```
/\x28([^\x29]+)\x29/
```

Comment: -1. Seriously? This is a bit too obvious if you are trying for the obfuscated perl contest. For anything else, fail.

Comment: It's all in the eye of the beholder; if you do this all day and mentally immediately convert from hex values to what character it is, I can see this being a net win.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I had expected the "greedy" principle to apply, eating all the way to the close parenthesis even when nested.  Perhaps a little brute force, using index and rindex functions, would be better.

But I still wonder, why doesn't

```
$str =~ s/[ ]?\(.*?\)[ ]?//g;
```

slurp it all the way to the last ')'?

Comment: It slurps too much, but not to the last ')'. Your use of '.*?' says "match anything, but don't be greedy about it.' Consider "A (doubly (nested) remark) string". Your expression turns this into "Aremark) string". And what's with those `[ ]?` terms? Aren't regular expressions bad enough as is?

Comment: `[ ]` is a common way to include a literal space in a visible way in a regex (particularly under /x)

Answer (score 0):

A split version. I kind of like split for this, because it is non-invasive, preserving the original format, and also, regexes tend to become... complicated. Though you need regex to trim it, of course.

You'd still need to work out the spacing. It is not a simple thing to predict whether extra space will appear in the front or end, and removing all double spaces will not preserve original format. This solution removes a single space in front of opening parens, and nothing else. Works in most cases, assuming the input has correct punctuation to begin with.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @parts = split /\(/;
    print de_paren(@parts);
}

sub de_paren {
    my $return = shift;
    my @parts = @_;
    while (my $word = shift @parts) {
        next unless $word =~ /\)/;
        $word =~ s/^.*?\)// while ($word =~ /\)/);
        $return =~ s/ $//;
        $return .= $word;
    }
    return $return;
}

__DATA__
A (doubly (no, (triply!) nested)) string
This is a (extra stuff) string.
(Preliminary remark)  string
String (with end remark) String (with end remark)
A string (remark before punctuation)!
A (doubly (nested)) string
```

Output is:

```
A string
This is a string.
  string
String String
A string!
A string ->
```